# C# - Windows CE: form translation independent of OS culture settings

Tags: c#, localization, windows-ce, translation

I am writing a program in C# for a Windows CE device and would like the application to be translated according to a language setting in the application itself.

I have already read some articles about localisation using resource files and translating forms using the 'Localizable' and 'Language' properties. From what I have read I understand that this type of form translation works with the OS language setting (correct me if I am wrong).

Now I am looking for a way to do the form translation dependent on my own in-program language setting, preferably using resource files.

I have already thought of doing this translation in the Load event of each form but maybe there are other solutions or best-practice for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Language.resx, Language.[language]-[country].resx way of localizing, the generated class Language will have a property named Culture that can be set to override the current system culture.

```
Language.Culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
label1.Text = Language.my_language_string;
```

If you want to use the ResourceManager-class it has a member GetResourceSet() that takes a parameter CultureInfo. I haven't tried to use GetResourceSet myself but it sounds like something you could use.

```
ResourceManager CultureResourceManager = new ResourceManager("My.Language.Assembly", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
ResourceSet resourceSet = CultureResourceManager.GetResourceSet("sv-SE", true, true);
resourceSet.GetString("my_language_resource");
```

MSDN-link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset(v=vs.80).aspxo

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put it in the Load event, consider making a template form. Somewhere in the template form, add your localisation checks. Then, have your other forms inherit the template, and they will get the Load event by default.